# Python Function not returning correct value when attempting to divide but ok when subtraction?

Tags: python, function, return, divide

```
insideCount2 = 10
numberDarts2 = 50
print "inside count", insideCount2
print "numberDarts", numberDarts2
approximationOfPi = float(insideCount2 // numberDarts2)
return approximationOfPi
```

I have this as part of a function...

But in the appoximationOfPi line if I put a minus sign it works,

Im trying to divide and get a floating point number :/

Can anyone please help? I've been struggling for hours and have no idea.

Comment: What is your expected result and how does it differ from what the code gives you now?  If you want a "float" result, did you specify integer division (`//`) on purpose?

Comment: I wanted to get a float and before it would just give me 0.0. And Yes, I did. Thanks guys! :)!

Answer (score 0):

You need this in Python 3:

```
approximationOfPi = insideCount2 / numberDarts2
```

Or this in any version:

```
approximationOfPi = float(insideCount2) / numberDarts2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
approximationOfPi = float(insideCount2 / numberDarts2)
```

change this statement to

```
approximationOfPi = float(insideCount2) / float(numberDarts2)
```